# .get_dummies() works alone but doesnt save within function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a dataset and I want to make a function that does the `.get_dummies()` so I can use it in a pipeline for specific columns.

When I run `dataset = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=['Embarked','Sex'], drop_first=True)`
alone it works, as in, when I run `df.head()` I can still see the dummified columns but when I have a function like this,

```
def dummies(df):
    df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Embarked','Sex'], drop_first=True)
    
    return df
```

Once I run `dummies(dataset)` it shows me the dummified columsn in that same cell but when I try to `dataset.head()` it isn't dummified anymore.

What am I doing wrong?
thanks.

Comment: you need to save the result in a variable, either a new one or the same one, like for example `newdataset=dummies(dataset)`and then you can do `newdataset.head()`

Comment: @Copperfield isn't df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Embarked','Sex'], drop_first=True) 
that is me saving it in the same variable. I just want to overwrite it rather than putting it in a new variable. How can I fix that?

Comment: the variable df declared within the function dummies is only local to the function..  as @Copperfield indicated To make the external df equal the inner df, you need to call the dummies function like ```df = dummies(df) ```.  then, the inner df is assigned to the outer  df on return.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the result of the function to df, call the function like:

```
dataset=dummies(dataset)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get it to work just by running the function?

Comment: you're welcome! you mean like doing a C style pass by reference?

Comment: The reason being I need it to be done using the function alone.
`def dummies(ds):
    ds = pd.get_dummies(ds, columns=['Embarked','Sex'], drop_first=True)
    return ds`

because later on the pipeline looks like this:
`pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('impute_age',DataframeFunctionTransformer(age_imputer)),
    ('impute_embarked',DataframeFunctionTransformer(embarked_imputer)),
    ('getdummies',DataframeFunctionTransformer(dummies)),
    ('scaling',DataframeFunctionTransformer(scaling)),
    ('clf',GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=4, n_estimators=150, learning_rate=0.05))
    
])`

Comment: have you tried to return a copy? maybe something like: def dummies(df):
    return pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['Embarked', 'Sex'], drop_first=True).copy()

Answer (score 0):

function inside them have their own independent namespace for variable defined there either in the signature or inside

for example

```
a = 0
def fun(a):
    a=23
    return a
fun(a)
print("a is",a) #a is 0
```

here you might think that `a` will have the value 23 at the end, but that is not the case because the `a` inside of `fun` is not the same `a` outside, when you call `fun(a)` what happens is that you pass into the function a reference to the real object that is somewhere in memory so the `a` inside will have the same reference and thus the same value.
With `a=23` you're changing what this `a` points to, which in this example is 23.
And with `fun(a)` the function itself return a value, but without this being saved somewhere that result get lost.

To update the variable outside you need to reassigned to the result of the function

```
a = 0
def fun(a):
    a=23
    return a
a = fun(a)
print("a is",a) #a is 23
```

which in your case it would be `dataset=dummies(dataset)`

If you want that your function make changes in-place to the object it receive, you can't use `=`, you need to use something that the object itself provide to allow modifications in place, for example

this would not work

```
a = []
def fun2(a):
    a=[23]
    return a
fun2(a)
print("a is",a) #a is []
```

but this would

```
a = []
def fun2(a):
    a.append(23)
    return a
fun2(a)
print("a is",a) #a is [23]
```

because we are using a in-place modification method that the object provided, in this example that would be the append method form list

But such modification in place can result in unforeseen result, specially if the object being modify is shared between processes, so I rather recomend the previous approach

Comment: Understood! Thank you. The problem for me is that the `.get_dummies()` function doesn't provide something an in-place modification like for example `.fillna()` which has an `inplace=True` parameter.

Comment: that isn't really a problem, just do `dataset=dummies(dataset)` and from this point on dataset wil be the modify version, or you can do `newdataset=dummies(dataset)` and work with newdataset from this point on, this have the bonus that you keep the previous version around in the variable dataset which might be useful for something